# How to get the order of a type a elliptic curve group G?

Tags: encryption

Type a elliptic curve can be generated by reading a file like:

const char pbpdp::params[400] =
"type a\n
q 8780710799663312522437781984754049815806883199414208211028653399266475630880222957078625179422662221423155858769582317459277713367317481324925129998224791\n
h 12016012264891146079388821366740534204802954401251311822919615131047207289359704531102844802183906537786776\n
r 730750818665451621361119245571504901405976559617\n
exp2 159\n
exp1 107\n
sign1 1\n
sign0 1";

Is q the order of this group?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Check Q = h * r ?